# Cannot compile with TSDuck in GCC 8.3.1

Tags: c++, gcc

- TSDuck Version 3.27.2438
- GCC Version 8.3.1
- Centos 7.9

I am trying to compile some code against TSDuck (RPM install version 3.27-2438). I get a compile error on UString.h. GCC seems to be unhappy with the use of a const_iterator in the erase function. As I understand it, this has been allowed since C++11 and should be implemented in GCC 8.3.1. Has anyone else run into this issue? It seems like a compiler bug, but I've also tried it in GCC 9.3.1 and gotten the same error.

Error:

```
/usr/include/tsduck/tsUString.h:2088:84: error: no matching function for call to ‘ts::UString::erase(std::basic_string<char16_t>::const_iterator&)’
         iterator erase(const_iterator position) { return SuperClass::erase(position); }
                                                                                    ^
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/string:52,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/stdexcept:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/array:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unique_ptr.h:37,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/memory:80,
                 from /workspaces/ts_reader/src/ts_reader/ts_reader.cpp:4:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:4632:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
       erase(size_type __pos = 0, size_type __n = npos)
       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:4632:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char16_t>::const_iterator’ {aka ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char16_t*, std::basic_string<char16_t> >’} to ‘std::basic_string<char16_t>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’}
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:4648:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char16_t*, std::basic_string<char16_t> >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char16_t*]’
       erase(iterator __position)
       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:4648:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__normal_iterator<const char16_t*,[...]>’ to ‘__normal_iterator<char16_t*,[...]>’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:4668:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char16_t*, std::basic_string<char16_t> >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char16_t*]’
       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last);
       ^~~~~
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] and show the exact command used to compile the code. Fwiw, I didn't get this compilation error when using a `ts:UString` and calling its `erase()` member function with a `std::basic_string<char16_t>::const_iterator` (`ts::UString::const_iterator`).

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are using the C++11 ABI.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html

> _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
>
> Defined to the value 1 by default. Configurable via --disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi and/or --with-default-libstdcxx-abi. ABI-changing. When defined to a non-zero value the library headers will use the new C++11-conforming ABI introduced in GCC 5, rather than the older ABI introduced in GCC 3.4. This changes the definition of several class templates, including std:string, std::list and some locale facets. For more details see [Dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html).